# Creating native-script RadSideDrawer

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I've been trying to do a RadSideDrawer and I've been having issues getting it to work and recognize the RadSideDrawer part. I get an error message saying "calling js method onCreateView failed" here's some code to show what i'm trying to do. I'm just wondering is there an issue declaring or importing RadListView.

```
//drawer.component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { ActionItem } from "ui/action-bar";
import { Observable } from "data/observable";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,    
    templateUrl: 'drawer.component.html'
})
export class SideDrawerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    private _mainContentText: string;

    constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.mainContentText = "SideDrawer for NativeScript can be easily setup in the HTML definition of your page by defining tkDrawerContent and tkMainContent. The component has a default transition and position and also exposes notifications related to changes in its state. Swipe from left to open side drawer.";
    }

    get mainContentText() {
        return this._mainContentText;
    }

    set mainContentText(value: string) {
        this._mainContentText = value;
    }

    public openDrawer() {
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
    }

    public onCloseDrawerTap() {
       this.drawer.closeDrawer();
    }
}
```

---

```
//drawer.component.html
<RadSideDrawer #sidedrawerId tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <AbsoluteLayout tkMainContent dock="top" >
        <Button class="header-bar"></Button>
        <Image src="res://logo" height="77" width="95" class="logo"></Image>
        <Button left="250" text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)="openDrawer()" class="drawerContentButton"></Button>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
            <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <Label text="Close Drawer" color="lightgray" padding="10" style="horizontal-align: center" (tap)="onCloseDrawerTap()"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

Comment: which tutorial are you following?